I am looking for a procedure which will allow me to know how many processes, once reached can be critical for my ubuntu server 22.04
personally I would like to use it in a monitoring framework on nagios core with the check_procs command. The objective is that I can be alerted when the number of critical processes is reached

Is there some sort of formula that allows to determine the number of critical processes on an Ubuntu server based on the machine's resources?

Short answer: Not possible.

There is really no such maximum number of allowed processes, as different processes may consume different amount of CPU cycles and memory.
If the resources required by each process were infinitesimally small, then you could get as many processes as you want.
